# Django postgres "No migrations to apply" troubleshoot

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I had to modify the table of my app so I dropped it from postgres database (using `objectname.objects.all().delete()` in django python shell and with postgres at PGAdmin).

I deleted the appname `migrations` folder. When I run python `manage.py makemigrations appname`, the folder migrations gets created with a `0001_initial.py` creating the tables.
When I run `python manage.py migrate appname`, nothing happens and I cannot see the tables in postgres PGAdmin.

```
(website) C:\Users\Folder>python manage.py makemigrations appname
Migrations for 'appname':
  food\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Table1
    - Create model Table2
    - Create index Table2_search__7dd784_gin on field(s) search_vector of model Table2

(website) C:\Users\Folder>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, appname, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

When I deleted the folder migrations I can see the migrations are gone with `python manage.py showmigrations`.

I also tried `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` but still no result.

```
(website) C:\Users\Folder>python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, postgres, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, appname, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Any other idea on what may be happening? Maybe postgres full_text_search index is messing it up?
Any idea on how to get the tables in postgres again?

Comment: In Postgres, and any db, Django itself makes a table to keep track of Migrations it has ran so it doesn't get all wack. What I believe is happening is you're running Migration #1 for App #1, but that table has an entry saying it's already been ran.
You can try to remove the entry in that table or just delete & remake the entire db; I always do #2, I hope this isn't a Prod problem. Next time, delete tables/models through Django Migrations instead of the shell+PgAdmin and this won't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `python manage.py migrate appname zero`?
It will migrate to the state before creating any models in the app.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations